# problems using regex expressions re.search and re.compile

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, syntax-error

A stack overflow user has kindly shown me to https://pythex.org/ which allows you to build and test regular expressions.

I have successfully been able to write just the expression but when it comes to actually using it in python with the re. module I am confused.

What I don't understand is when to use.compile, and when to do re.search -->

if I search for the text inside of brackets for example and there is more than one, I gather I am supposed to use .group[x] where x is the index of the item you want to return

**Example**

```
pattern = re.compile(r'View All \((\d*)\)')
number = pattern.search(data).group(2);
```

As I understand if I had the following, the number_connections variable, when printed would be

```
View All (8) View All (16) View All (12)
```

**Result**

```
Print number
16
```

What I don't get is: When there is more than one occurance of the text you are looking for how do you loop over them, and how do you get a count of how many there are?

```
For example: number.count() would return, found 3
for i in number: (this doesn't work because match is a regular expression object???)
    print i
```

But What happens when there is only one of the text you are looking for in the regular expression?

**Example**

Regular Expression: 
    pattern = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]*\s[a-zA-Z]*/[a-zA-Z]*/[a-zA-Z]*')
    email = pattern.search(data).group(1);

Result

```
data: "email-id":"FisrtName LastName/Australia/ABC"}]</p></body></html>
should return: firstname lastname/Australia/ABC
```

There may or may not be more than one of these on the page - in which case always using result[0] will not work, as there may be only one instance of the email address on the page.

Now I realise my syntax is obviously wrong but doing this also gave me the following, so I'm looking for guidance on how to use the regular expression properly once I have built it using https://pythex.org/:

```
email = pattern.search(data)
print email

<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0553B090>
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you're at a stage with Python regex where you need to read a bit of documentation or a full tutorial—rather than trying to acquire knowledge in disconnected pieces.

You have access to exactly the same match whether you compile the regex or not.

Quoting [Jan Goyvaerts](http://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html), author of RegexBuddy and co-author of the *Regular Expressions Cookbook*:

> If you want to use the same regular expression more than once, you
>   should compile it into a regular expression object. Regular expression
>   objects are more efficient, and make your code more readable. To
>   create one, just call re.compile(regex) or re.compile(regex, flags).
>   The flags are the matching options described above for the re.search()
>   and re.match() functions.
>
> The regular expression object returned by re.compile() provides all
>   the functions that the re module also provides directly: search(),
>   match(), findall(), finditer(), sub() and split(). The difference is
>   that they use the pattern stored in the regex object, and do not take
>   the regex as the first parameter. re.compile(regex).search(subject) is
>   equivalent to re.search(regex, subject).

For multiple matches, you can use `findall` or `finditer` (more details on the same page).